# How to convert PDF Base64 into pdf then PDF into an image in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, file-conversion

following is the code added:
The image object is in the `library.imaging`.

```
"using System.Drawing;"
"using System.Drawing.Imaging;"
{
  byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAA");
  Image image;
  using (MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream(b))
  {
    image = Image.FromStream(memstr);
  }
}
```

Here is the new code I'm working on:

```
{
  string base64BinaryStr = " ";
  byte[] PDFDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);
  string FileName = (@"C:\Users\Downloads\PDF " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm"));

  BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(FileName + ".pdf"));            
  writer.Write(PDFDecoded);
  string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PDFDecoded);
}
```

Comment: Break your problem down. Those are two different things you're trying to achieve and one of them is almost certainly irrelevant to whatever you're stuck on. And what does this question have to do with your **date**-conversion tag?

Comment: yes,in first step BAse64 to pdf and then same pdf Into Image

Comment: OK, which part are you stuck with?

Comment: @john sorry for wrong tag

Comment: i am done with the first part but the problem is that it creates empty file ,means there is no data in it

Comment: There's no evidence in your question of you ever creating a file, so that doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @john i am working to sort this out why these newly created files are empty ???

Comment: MemoryStream, is in memory, it will never get saved to a file. That aside though, Converting a pdf to image will take the use of a library

Comment: @john all evidences are added now

Comment: I think you wanted `File.WriteAllBytes(FileName + ".pdf", PDFDecoded);`

Comment: @MichaelRandall i think so. because i was lookiing for it but there was no solution except Includin libraries.Thank you .can you Please Suggest me anyone which you have used ?

Comment: Note that more recent versions of the PDF format include binary data, and that using string encoding with arbitrary binary data won't give you reliable results because byte[] -> string -> byte[] won't necessarily result in the same byte[] at the end as you had at the start. String encoding isn't built for binary data.

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(FileName + ".pdf", PDFDecoded);    @john its not working

Comment: @John By the way ,thank you

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? The only way I can see that it wouldn't "work" is that a) the file handle is locked open by something (perhaps your own code somewhere?), so C# can't open it or b) PDFDecoded doesn't contain the data you expect, so naturally what's written isn't what you expect.

Comment: its working now, thank you @John

Answer (score 3):

So this is your current code:

```
byte[] PDFDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);
string FileName = (@"C:\Users\Downloads\PDF " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm"));

BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(FileName + ".pdf"));            
writer.Write(PDFDecoded);
```

You don't actually need `BinaryWriter` for this. `File.Create` already gives you a `FileStream`:

```
FileStream writer = File.Create(FileName + ".pdf");
writer.Write(PDFDecoded, 0, PDFDecoded.Length);
```

But this will still have the problem you're experiencing because you're not flushing the data to it. We also need to close the file. Thankfully, we can wrap it in `using` and it will do both for us:

```
using (FileStream writer = File.Create(FileName + ".pdf"))
{
    writer.Write(PDFDecoded, 0, PDFDecoded.Length); 
}
```

But a simpler way to do this is:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(FileName + ".pdf", PDFDecoded);
```

As for PDF -> Image, you'll probably have to see if there is a library available for this (search "PDF to Image NuGet") that can help you with this as I don't think there is anything built-in.

Comment: @Zoraiz if I solved your problem, please can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, you don't need to create a physical PDF file, you can have it in memory and convert it to image from there.

Now the problem is that you cannot use `Image` from `System.Drawing.Imaging` for this, it doesn't support reading PDF file.

Instead you'll need to search for some library that can do that.
For example, try [GemBox.Pdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Pdf/), you can use it like this:

```
string base64String = "...";
byte[] pdfBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(pdfBytes)))
{
    ImageSaveOptions imageOptions = new ImageSaveOptions(ImageSaveFormat.Png);

    string imageName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm") + ".png";
    pdfDocument.Save(@"C:\Users\Downloads\" + imageName, imageOptions);
}
```

I've used the code provided on this [Convert](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-convert-pdf-to-image/208) example.

Comment: i also need the Pdf File @hertzogth